# Empty field validation not working using simple_form_for in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

i am using **gem 'simple_form'** for my form. The form is working fine but When I tried to implement empty field validation (by passing validate: true in the input tag), it is not working.
And if i pass *input_html: { maxlength: 20 }* etc; it is working fine.

_form.html.erb:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@employee, @insurance]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :name_of_dependent, required: true %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.input :relationship %>
   </div>
<br/>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-success btn-md' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

simple_form.en.yml:

```
en:
  simple_form:
    "yes": 'Yes'
    "no": 'No'
    required:
      text: 'required'
      mark: '*'
      # You can uncomment the line below if you need to overwrite the whole required html.
      # When using html, text and mark won't be used.
      # html: '<abbr title="required">*</abbr>'
    error_notification:
      default_message: "Please review the problems below:"
    # Labels and hints examples
    # labels:
    #   defaults:
    #     password: 'Password'
    #   user:
    #     new:
    #       email: 'E-mail to sign in.'
    #     edit:
    #       email: 'E-mail.'
    # hints:
    #   defaults:
    #     username: 'User name to sign in.'
    #     password: 'No special characters, please.'
```

and my controller code is:

```
  def new
      @employee = Employee.find(params[:employee_id])
     @insurance = @employee.insurances.build
  end

  def create
    @employee = Employee.find(params[:employee_id])
    @insurance = @employee.insurances.create(insurance_params)
    redirect_to employee_path(@employee)  
  end

   def insurance_params
      params.require(:insurance).permit(:name_of_dependent, :relationship)
    end
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Without testing: I had the same problem and installed [Nilify_Blanks](https://rubygems.org/gems/nilify_blanks)